# HBase Go client error

Tags: java, hadoop, go, hbase, hdfs

I want to operate the HBase DB with a Go client to create a table, but there is a problem I cannot fix.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/tsuna/gohbase"
    "github.com/tsuna/gohbase/hrpc"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
    admin := gohbase.NewAdminClient("master")
    columns := []string{"cf"}
    createReq := hrpc.NewCreateTable(context.Background(), []byte("goTest"), columns)
    result, err := admin.CreateTable(createReq)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("err:", err)
    }
    log.Println("result:", result)
}
```

when I run the code below, it gives me a Java exception:

```
ym@master:~/gopath/src/test$ go run hbase_createtable.go 
2016/05/05 17:22:59 Connected to 192.168.0.116:2181
2016/05/05 17:22:59 Authenticated: id=95836126668718124, timeout=30000
2016/05/05 17:22:59 Recv loop terminated: err=EOF
2016/05/05 17:22:59 Send loop terminated: err=<nil>
2016/05/05 17:22:59 err: HBase Java exception java.io.IOException: 
java.io.IOException: null
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor.getMaxVersions(HColumnDescriptor.java:617)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.sanityCheckTableDescriptor(HMaster.java:1582)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.createTable(MasterRpcServices.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:52195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2117)
        ... 4 more

2016/05/05 17:22:59 result: <nil>
```

I know nothing about Java, and this problem puzzled me several days.
I am sure the hbase server on master working normal, because I can create a table from shell.

I would appreciate if someone could help fix this exception...

Comment: Hi I don't know much about go. But error clearly says its number format exception due to parsing  "unaccepted value" which is not an integer with Integer.parseInt . Can you investigate in that angle ?

Comment: i have not learn about java,that is why i choose go client.so,i have no idea  about this java exception.whatever,thank you.

Comment: @youzhi.he What version of HBase server you try to connect?

Comment: the hbase version is 1.1.4

Comment: hdfs version is 2.6.4